# iOS OpenGL ES Crash loading same object multiple times

Tags: ios, opengl-es, crash

Basically, in my iOS app, i have a modal screen, in which i display some OpenGL ES graphics. I am able to enter and exit this modal screen 6 times, before the application crashes. I'm assuming this is a memory issue, but i'm stuck as to what and / or where.

Any help on this matter is incredibly appreciated.

In my OGLViewController:

```
#define OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK {GLuint error = glGetError(); ((error == GL_NO_ERROR) ? :  NSLog(@"GL Error: %d", (error)));}

@interface OGLItemViewController : GLKViewController

@property (nonatomic) GLuint program;

// item ogl arrays + buffers
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger numOGLBuffers;
@property (nonatomic) GLuint* vertexArrays;
@property (nonatomic) GLuint* vertexBuffers;

// index buffer for ogl item vertices
@property (nonatomic) GLuint* indexBuffers;

@property (strong, nonatomic) EAGLContext *context;
@property (strong, nonatomic) GLKBaseEffect *effect;

@end

@implementation

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  self.context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];

  OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK
  glFinish(); // put this in here to make sure all previous calls have been finished
  OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK

  if (!self.context)
  {
    NSLog(@"Failed to create ES context");
  }

  GLKView *view = (GLKView *) self.view;
  view.context = self.context;
  view.drawableDepthFormat = GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat24;
  view.opaque = NO;

  self.numOGLBuffers = 0;

  self.vertexArrays = nil;
  self.vertexBuffers = nil;
  self.indexBuffers = nil;
}

- (void)setupGL
{
  OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK
  [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];
  OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK

  [self loadShaders];    
  OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK

  self.effect = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc] init];
  OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK
  self.effect.light0.enabled = GL_TRUE;
  OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK

  self.effect.colorMaterialEnabled = GL_TRUE;
  OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK

  self.effect.lightModelTwoSided = GL_FALSE;
  OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK

  self.effect.light0.diffuseColor = GLKVector4Make(0.69f, 0.69f, 0.69f, 0.5f);
  OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK

  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK

  Item *item = [GlobalStore sharedInstance].item

  NSMutableArray *shells = item.geometry;

  if (shells.count > 0)
  {    
    _vertexArrays = malloc(shells.count * sizeof(GLuint));
    _vertexBuffers = malloc(shells.count * sizeof(GLuint));
    _indexBuffers = malloc(shells.count * sizeof(GLuint));
    self.numOGLBuffers = shells.count;

    for (int i = 0; i < shells.count; i++)
    {
        Geometry *geom = [shells objectAtIndex:i];
        if (geom.vertexCount > 0)
        {
            GLuint vao = 0;
            OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK
            glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &vao);

            OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK
            glBindVertexArrayOES(vao);
            OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK

            _vertexArrays[i] = vao;

            if (!geom.vertices)
            {
                [self displayError:-998];  // generic error codes that i've just canned in to see if any problems with these pointers
            }
            if (!geom.indices)
            {
                [self displayError:-997];
            }

            // create vertice buffer
            GLuint vbo = 0;
            glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
            OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
            OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK
            glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, geom.vertexCount * sizeof(OGLVertices), geom.vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
            OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK

            _vertexBuffers[i] = vbo;

            // create index by buffer
            GLuint ibo = 0;
            glGenBuffers(1, &ibo);
            OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK
            glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
            OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK
            glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, geom.indexCount * sizeof(GLuint), geom.indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
            OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK

            _indexBuffers[i] = ibo;

            // enable position, normal and colour attributes
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
            OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK
            glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(OGLVertices), (const GLvoid *) offsetof(OGLVertices, Position));
            OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);
            OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK
            glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(OGLVertices), (const GLvoid *) offsetof(OGLVertices, Normal));
            OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribColor);
            OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK
            glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribColor, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(OGLVertices), (const GLvoid *) offsetof(OGLVertices, Colour));
            OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK
        }
      }

      glBindVertexArrayOES(0);
      OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK
  }
}

- (void)tearDownGL
{
  [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];
  self.effect = nil;

  [self deleteOGLData];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
  [self tearDownGL];

  if ([EAGLContext currentContext] == self.context)
  {
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:nil];
  }
}

- (void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [self tearDownGL];
}

- (void)deleteOGLData
{
    // delete ogl buffers and arrays
    if (self.numOGLBuffers > 0)
  {
    if (_vertexBuffers)
    {
        OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK
        glDeleteBuffers(self.numOGLBuffers, _vertexBuffers);

        OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK
        free(_vertexBuffers);
        _vertexBuffers = nil;
    }
    if (_vertexArrays)
    {
        glDeleteVertexArraysOES(self.numOGLBuffers, _vertexArrays);
        OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK
        free(_vertexArrays);
        _vertexArrays = nil;
    }
    if (_indexBuffers)
    {
        glDeleteBuffers(self.numOGLBuffers, _indexBuffers);
        OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK
        free(_indexBuffers);
        _indexBuffers = nil;
    }
  }


  self.numOGLBuffers = 0;

  glDeleteProgram(self.program);
  OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK

  self.program = 0;

  glFinish(); // again, just put this in here to check everything has finished
  OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK
}

- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{ 
    OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK

    // Render the object with GLKit
    [self.effect prepareToDraw];
    OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK


    NSMutableArray *shells = [GlobalStore sharedInstance].item.geometry;
    if (shells && _vertexArrays && _vertexBuffers)
    {          
        for (int i = 0; i < shells.count; i++)
        {
            Geometry *geom = [shells objectAtIndex:i];

            if (geom.vertexCount > 0)
            {
                GLuint vao = self.vertexArrays[i];
                glBindVertexArrayOES(vao);
                OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK

                if(geom.indexCount == 0)
                    [self displayError:-996];

                glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, geom.indexCount, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
                OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK
                self.initialised = YES;
            }
        }        
    }
}

- (BOOL)loadShaders
{
  GLuint vertShader, fragShader;
  NSString *vertShaderPathname, *fragShaderPathname;

  // Create shader program.
  self.program = glCreateProgram();
  OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK

  // Create and compile vertex shader.
  vertShaderPathname = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Shader" ofType:@"vsh"];
  if (![self compileShader:&vertShader type:GL_VERTEX_SHADER file:vertShaderPathname])
  {
    NSLog(@"Failed to compile vertex shader");
    return NO;
  }

  // Create and compile fragment shader.
  fragShaderPathname = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Shader" ofType:@"fsh"];
  if (![self compileShader:&fragShader type:GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER file:fragShaderPathname])
  {
    NSLog(@"Failed to compile fragment shader");
    return NO;
  }

  // Attach vertex shader to program.
  glAttachShader(_program, vertShader);
  OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK

  // Attach fragment shader to program.
  glAttachShader(_program, fragShader);
  OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK

  // Bind attribute locations.
  // This needs to be done prior to linking.
  glBindAttribLocation(_program, GLKVertexAttribPosition, "position");
  OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK

  glBindAttribLocation(_program, GLKVertexAttribNormal, "normal");
  OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK

  // Link program.
  if (![self linkProgram:_program])
  {
    NSLog(@"Failed to link program: %d", _program);

    if (vertShader)
    {
        glDeleteShader(vertShader);
        OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK
        vertShader = 0;
    }
    if (fragShader)
    {
        glDeleteShader(fragShader);
        OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK
        fragShader = 0;
    }
    if (_program)
    {
        glDeleteProgram(_program);
        OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK
        _program = 0;
    }

    return NO;
  }

  // Get uniform locations.
  uniforms[UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTION_MATRIX] = glGetUniformLocation(_program, "modelViewProjectionMatrix");
  uniforms[UNIFORM_NORMAL_MATRIX] = glGetUniformLocation(_program, "normalMatrix");

  // Release vertex and fragment shaders.
  if (vertShader)
  {
    glDetachShader(_program, vertShader);
    OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK
    glDeleteShader(vertShader);
    OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK
  }
  if (fragShader)
  {
    glDetachShader(_program, fragShader);
    OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK
    glDeleteShader(fragShader);
    OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK
  }

  return YES;
}

- (BOOL)compileShader:(GLuint *)shader type:(GLenum)type file:(NSString *)file
{
  GLint status;
  const GLchar *source;

  source = (GLchar *)[[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:file encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil] UTF8String];
  if (!source)
  {
    NSLog(@"Failed to load vertex shader");
    return NO;
  }

  *shader = glCreateShader(type);
  OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK
  glShaderSource(*shader, 1, &source, NULL);
  OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK
  glCompileShader(*shader);
  OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK

  glGetShaderiv(*shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
  OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK
  if (status == 0)
  {
    glDeleteShader(*shader);
    OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK
    return NO;
  }

  return YES;
}

- (BOOL)linkProgram:(GLuint)prog
{
  GLint status;
  glLinkProgram(prog);
  OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK

  glGetProgramiv(prog, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status);
  OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK
  if (status == 0)
  {
    return NO;
  }

  return YES;
}

- (BOOL)validateProgram:(GLuint)prog
{
  GLint logLength, status;

  glValidateProgram(prog);
  OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK
  glGetProgramiv(prog, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLength);
  OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK
  if (logLength > 0)
  {
    GLchar *log = (GLchar *)malloc(logLength);
    glGetProgramInfoLog(prog, logLength, &logLength, log);
    OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK
    NSLog(@"Program validate log:\n%s", log);
    free(log);
  }

  glGetProgramiv(prog, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS, &status);
  OPENGL_ERROR_CHECK
  if (status == 0)
  {
    return NO;
  }

  return YES;
}


-(void)displayError: (GLuint) err
{
  NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"OpenGL Error: %d", err];
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Error"
                                                  message: msg
                                                 delegate:self
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];

  [alert show];
}


@end
```

Now - i don't know if it's the right way to do this, but in the viewdiddisappear method, i make sure to delete all the ogl data. i wanted to make sure that when i exited the view, the ogl data is deleted from memory.

So, if i enter the modal view, exit, and repeat 5 more times, i will get a black screen crash, and will break, with the following screen:

[image: screen grab]

I have made sure everything is done in a single thread where appropriate. I have tried to make sure all objects and buffers are deleted.

So i'm wondering what on earth am i doing wrong to cause it to suddenly crash..... Nothing in the profiler seems to indicate anything. I don't seem to have any memory leaks or anything too substantial that would cause memory to run out.

( i do know i'm rendering every frame, when i dont need to - i will address this at a later point.)

The globalstore i have holds an instance of some objects that i use. These should always be valid (i've checked).

Comment: Did you try to add the breakpoint on all exceptions? If you're lucky it should be able to catch the exact reason of the crash, just go to the breakpoint navigator, bottom left corner, press the '+' and "Add Exception Breakpoint" and 'Done'. Now go reproduce the crash and examine the stack trace to see which part of your code is the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

What i needed to do, was to delete the GLKView drawables.

In the ViewDidDisappear method (might not be the proper place, but it works) add the following:

```
GLKView *view = (GLKView*) self.view;
[view deleteDrawable];
```

Comment: There was actually something weird going on - whereby the viewdidload method was being called when the view was exiting. So what happens would be that i would deallocate all the appropriate memory upon exiting the screen, and then the viewdidload method would be called, and all the memory allocations set up again.